# pagination breaks when i + 1

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am using a pagination plugin called pajinate, i need to provide a Show All option, so I am passing in the index of my ajax call to the "item_per_page".  Everything works great, but I need to add 1 to the index, so i get the full results.

When i set the "item_per_page" to just "i", it works, when i set it to "i + 1", it does not.  Doesn't make sense to me:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "search-by-department-621650415.json",
    cache: true,
    dataType : 'json',

    success : function(results) {
        var employeeData = [];
        var totalNum;
        var startNum = 9;   
        $.each(results.data, function(i, item){
            employeeData.push({
                departmentName: item.departnemtName,
                firstname: item.firstName,
                lastname: item.lastName,
                phonework: item.workPhone
            });

            totalNum = i; 
            //totalNum = i + 1; breaks when i do this!!
        });

        $('#employee-name-results').tmpl(employeeData).appendTo('#name-results-container');

        Pagination(startNum);

        $("a.showall").click(function() {
            Pagination(totalNum);
        });

    } 

});


function Pagination(itemsPerPage) {
    $('#paging_container-1').pajinate({         
        items_per_page : itemsPerPage,
        num_page_links_to_display : 8,
        abort_on_small_lists: true,
        nav_label_prev : '<img src="images/icons/icon_prev.png"  />',
        nav_label_next : '<img src="images/icons/icon_next.png"  />'
    });
    console.log(itemsPerPage);
}
```

Comment: when just use 'i', it will remove the pagination and display all items, but with "i + 1' it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the if statement in the Plugin:

if (options.abort_on_small_lists && options.items_per_page >= $items.size()) return $page_container;

Needs to be:

if (options.abort_on_small_lists && options.items_per_page > $items.size()) return $page_container;

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var totalNum = 0;
```

This will explicitly set it as a numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing `i` to be a number: `totalNum = +i + 1;`

Javascript might be making it a string instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
$("a.showall").click(function() {
      Pagination(results.data.length);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting the right number, its just not getting passed into Pagination - items_per_page when i add + 1, for some odd reason?